# Multi threading socket - Not able to close the socket gracefully

Tags: java, networking, serversocket, webmethods

In my main thread I have a while(listening) loop which calls accept() on my ServerSocket object, then starts a new client thread and adds it to a Collection when a new client is accepted.
However, the accept() call in the while(listening) loop blocks and i'm struggling to close the connection.  please find my below sample code, is there any way to create wrapper service to close the socket connection for the below server side program.

```
public static final void serverSocket(IData pipeline) throws ServiceException {
    int clientNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket listener = null;
    int port =0;
    Properties socketProperties = new Properties();

    try
    {   
        listener = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println(listener.getLocalSocketAddress());           
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        while(true){
            new Connections(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    } 
    finally{

        try {
            listener.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static class Connections extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;


    public Connections(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
    }

   public void run()
    {
        try {

            // Send a welcome message to the client.

            while (true) 

            {

                // my program
            }
         catch (IOException e) {

            //exception
        } 

        finally {

            try {
                socket.close();

            } 
                catch (IOException e) {
       log.error("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
            }
            log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");

        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The connection should be closed when the `Connections` object either finishes what it is supposed to do or encounters EOS or a fatal `IOException` on the socket it is using. Examples abound. Unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have not adequately described the circumstances that dictate when you want to close.

In any case, your serverSocket object could become a static field that is made available to some other thread(s), and that other thread can decide when to close.

Comment: I would like to create a separate java code for stopping the socket port, how can we achieve it?

Comment: @Dil Make up your mind. If you want to stop the listening socket, just close it. But your question is about closing connections, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Got it, thanks :), sorry for confusing it.  Actually, now i'm facing another trouble.  For example,

Comment: 1) Opened my socket
2) Multithreading implemented – Waiting for connections
3) Created 4 connections and got response
4) Closed the socket –  However, I’m able to close only last connections (4th connection), previous connections(1 to 3) are still open.  
should i need to use destroy? I'm new to Java, trying to explore it. thanks

Comment: @Dil 1. Fix your question. 2. These are a whole lot of new questions, insufficiently explained, and 3 down here is not the place to ask them.